# Fitting models with multivarient time series data

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, time-series, classification, multivariate-testing

My main question is how do shape data to fit multivarient time series data on a model. My current code looks something like this:

```
def diff_stats_mod (X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    ################init########################
    score_dict = {}
    n=0

    ################Create a list of models to evaluate################
    models, names = list(), list()

    models.append(LogisticRegression())
    names.append('LR')

    models.append(DecisionTreeClassifier())
    names.append('DTC')

    models.append(SVC())
    names.append('SVM')

    models.append(RandomForestClassifier())
    names.append('RF')

    models.append(GradientBoostingClassifier())
    names.append('GBM')

    ################evaluate models################
    for i in range(len(models)):
        model = models[i]
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        pred = model.predict(X_test)
        not_include = 0

        ###############Ensure that the prediction is not all positive or all neg###############
        while len(set(pred)) == 1:
            model = models[i]
            model.fit(X_train, y_train)
            pred = model.predict(X_test)
            if n == 10:
                not_include = 1
                break
            n+=1

        ###############Exclude all models whos predictions are off the same class only###############
        if not_include != 1:
            confu_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred)
            fb_score = fbeta_score(y_test, pred, 0.9) * 100
            score_dict['{}'.format(names[i])] = fb_score
            score_dict['{} confusion matrix'.format(names[i])] = confu_mat

        else:
            fb_score = NaN
            score_dict['{}'.format(names[i])] = fb_score

    ################try a range of k values################
    for k in range(1, 11):
        ################Load and evaluate knn models################
        not_include = 0

        model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        pred = model.predict(X_test)

        ###############Ensure that the prediction is not all positive or all neg###############
        while len(set(pred)) == 1:
            model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
            model.fit(X_train, y_train)
            pred = model.predict(X_test)
            if n == 10:
                not_include = 1
                break
            n += 1

        ###############Exclude all models whos predictions are off the same class only###############
        if not_include != 1:
            confu_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred)
            fb_score = fbeta_score(y_test, pred, 0.9) * 100
            score_dict['KNN{}'.format(k)] = fb_score
            score_dict['KNN{} confusion matrix'.format(k)] = confu_mat

        else:
            fb_score = NaN
            score_dict['KNN{}'.format(k)] = fb_score

    return score_dict
```

Basically, this function returns the fbeta score of each model on the test set. It will re-train models that give a prediction of all the same class (up to ten times) and if after ten times, that specific model still outputs all predictions as the same class, it will exclude it.

This is a snippet of my data:

```
time_stamp          pxID    act                 hr
2015-06-06 17:00:00 7983    8.466666666666667   97.46555633544922
2015-06-06 17:30:00 7983    10.413333333333332  99.16444473266601
2015-06-06 18:00:00 7983    5.400000000000001   94.62666702270508
2015-06-06 18:30:00 7983    14.759999999999998  95.76777776082356
2015-06-06 19:00:00 7983    17.026666666666667  100.43111089070638
2015-08-04 10:30:00 8005    4.774020720186061   18.555715289243377
2015-08-04 11:00:00 8005    7.1056325549244574  20.01443100917877
2015-08-04 11:30:00 8005    9.088101464843694   24.019171214407546
2015-08-04 12:00:00 8005    4.32230745513258    20.9444548661983
2015-08-04 12:30:00 8005    4.464612178539353   18.433279992371574
2015-08-16 19:00:00 8026    1.4452551387583383  9.943809217794078
2015-08-16 19:30:00 8026    2.7265866427381216  13.206866297538518
2015-08-16 20:00:00 8026    2.2795014957992974  9.11883132666883
2015-08-16 20:30:00 8026    1.536946186246722   10.04255596582319
2015-08-16 21:00:00 8026    2.0673098515634667  9.219173212211949
```

Basically, there are numerous IDs and oberservations. When I tried to feed this data into the models, there was an error with regards to the dimension of the data. I know that models such as logistic regression can take in multidimensional inputs but I am not sure how to format the input for this and I am not sure what arguments I need to include in the LogisticRegression and other models so that it can handle multi dimensional data. For this classification problem, I would like to make use of the HR and Act data.

I am confused on how to tackle this problem as I am used to dealing with data where each row reflects one observation. However, this data shows that multiple rows reflect one observation.

My main question here is: How do I format my data to be used as inputs for SKlearn models?